# What is a "high" adjusted Rand index score?

Tags: clustering, heuristic

Does anyone know if there's a heuristic for a high or low adjusted Rand index? I understand this is rather subjective - and probably depends on the type of network data you're using. However, if anyone has any intuition for ranges of ARI scores, that would be very helpful!

I know that in the social sciences a correlation of 0 to .3 is considered low, .3 to .5 is considered medium, and .5 to 1 is considered high. I know this isn't perfect. But, it does give researchers some intuition for the effect they are finding.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but by "correlation," it sounds like you mean r-squared. The fact is that it's less about the academic field and more about the type of information or data. For instance, in direct marketing modeling the likelihood of someone responding "yes" to a magazine subscription offer, r-squares approach 0.0 can be profitable. With survey-based data, r-squares in the .1 to .2 range are quite normal. With business data, r-squares of .4 to .6 are typical. R-squares that go much higher than that are probably violating an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

ARI only works for *labeled* data. I.e. where you already know the "true" solution.

So even if there was a rule such as "ARI > 0.8 is good", it does not help solve any problem. Because you always know a solution that has an ARI of 1.0.

Comment: Can you use ARI to compare two different groupings of data? I.e.  I'm looking at email data and IM data and I'm interested in whether the natural "groups" are the same in both datasets. If I apply the same grouping algorithm to the same set of vertices (but different edges), could I compare the two groupings to see how similar they are using ARI?

Comment: You can use the ARI to see how similar two results are. It reduces to counting on how many *pairs* they agree and an adjustment for chance. Whether 0.8 is an unusually high similarity may still vary a lot between data sets (because there may be extreme structure such as duplicate points that ARI has not accounted for. On such data set, any two clustering results it may be hard to get a result not highly similar to all others.